# Annoying reset password error "Cannot save a new password" on Magento

Tags: php, magento

I am currently working with Magento 1.11.1.0 and i am getting a strange behaviour from the **reset password functionality**. When I try resetting my password, I end up getting the following error **"Cannot save a new password."** but when I follow the same steps on a different account, it works.

The accounts are exactly the same, the only difference is the email addresses. I have been trying to figure out what the problem is for 3 days but I haven't found anything yet.

**Does anyone know what the problem is or how to solve it.**

Comment: check for other user account activate.

Answer (score 0):

The "Cannot save a new password" error message is only thrown in one place (apologies I only have access to CE 1.9.2.1 currently, however, you should be able to grep search for it if it's not where I'm about to mention).

It's occurance is in app/code/core/Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php line 814.

```
try {
    // Empty current reset password token i.e. invalidate it
    $customer->setRpToken(null);
    $customer->setRpTokenCreatedAt(null);
    $customer->cleanPasswordsValidationData();
    $customer->save();
    $this->_getSession()->addSuccess(
        $this->_getHelper('customer')->__('Your password has been updated.'));
    $this->_redirect('*/*/login');
} catch (Exception $exception) {
    $this->_getSession()->addException($exception, $this->__('Cannot save a new password.'));
    $this->_redirect('*/*/resetpassword', array(
        'id' => $customerId,
        'token' => $resetPasswordLinkToken
    ));
    return;
}
```

This appears to be an exception thrown if it cannot save the customer. I'd follow this through and check your system.log and exception.log files to see why there is an issue saving this specific customer.

Comment: Thanks @Douglas. I added "$exception.getMessage()" to the error message output  and I got the following " Cannot save a new password. There is no active transaction ". Not sure what this means

Comment: This is a database exception.  Take a look at http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/61622/there-is-no-active-transaction-with-customer-registration-during-checkout (specifically the non approved answer) - take a look at your other modules for hooks that involve save() for a customer, and that would affect this one customer as opposed to others.